# Bluemix Message Hub - Failed to initialize SASL authentication yet still seems to work

Tags: python, ibm-cloud, sasl, kafka-python, message-hub

When I try to use the Bluemix Message Hub with Python, I keep receiving errors and failures.  Any ideas why given the below?

The errors are "Failed to initialize SASL authentication: SASL Handshake not supported by broker (required by mechanism PLAIN)"

However, when run my producer and consumer, they seem to work.  Messages are produced and messages are consumed.

I see the correct messages in my output that is intermingled with the error messages.

I have installed librdkafka and confirmed all looks OK per the instructions:

https://github.com/ibm-messaging/message-hub-samples/blob/master/docs/librdkafka.md

You can see my output here when I run ./config:

```
checking for libssl (by pkg-config)... failed
checking for libssl (by compile)... ok (cached)
checking for libsasl2 (by pkg-config)... failed
checking for libsasl2 (by compile)... ok (cached)

ENABLE_SSL               y
ENABLE_SASL              y
```

Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: What version of Kafka are you using?

Comment: I have:       confluent-kafka (0.9.4)
                  kafka-python (1.1.1)

Answer (score 0):

you may see that error message because of the recent version of librdkafka that you are using.
Message Hub is still running Kafka 10.0.0.1

please try adding this to your client configuration

```
api.version.request=true
```

Comment: I already am:                                                                                                                        'bootstrap.servers': opts['brokers'],
            'security.protocol': 'SASL_SSL',
            'ssl.ca.location': opts['ca_location'],
            'sasl.mechanisms': 'PLAIN',
            'sasl.username': opts['username'],
            'sasl.password': opts['password'],
            'api.version.request': True

Answer (score 0):

After updating from python 3.5.x to python 3.6, the errors go away.

Further, I updated anaconda to 4.3.8.